# Why doesn't this tool print the strings?

Tags: c, printf

this tool is for me to learn how to work with strings. but if it finished, sometimes, it should compare two dates (the systemdate and a entered birthday date) and tell the user how old the person is. but i get stuck. i wanted to try some basics at first, so the entered string gets split into day month and year and then it should print the strings.
But my real aim is, to convert them to an int value so that i can calculate with them.

But for some reasons the tool don't print the entered string, it just print 3 `\n` and i can't figure out the problem.

please help.

edit: fixed it again almost ready only the "btag" makes some some trouble. "bmonat" and "bjahr" works fine now thank u so far!

```
/*age check (c) By Tim Hartmann*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
SYSTEMTIME time;
GetSystemTime (&time);

char name[20], bday[10], bjahr[4], bmonat[3], btag[3]; 

int year = time.wYear;
int month = time.wMonth;
int day = time.wDay;
int intjahr, intmonat, inttag;


printf("\n\n today is the: %i.%i.%i \n\n",day,month,year);
printf(" please insert Birthdate (dd.mm.jjjj).\n\n");

gets(bday);

strncpy(bjahr , &bday[6], 4);
    bjahr[4] =  '\0';

strncpy(bmonat, &bday[3], 2);
    bmonat[2]=  '\0';        

strncpy(btag  , &bday[0], 2); /* here is the probleme */
    btag[2]  =  '\0'; 

printf("\n %s \n",   bjahr);
printf("\n %s \n",  bmonat);
printf("\n %s \n",    btag);

system("PAUSE");

 }
```

Comment: `scanf` will stop at the first whitespace character reached.. so make sure you are not entering that. Also I recommend you place a restriction such as `%9s` on the string read so you do not encounter a buffer overflow.

Comment: well the string that is given by the user contains no space. it has the format 00.00.0000 (the format of a typical date of course)

Answer (score 0):

The strings you declare (bday, bjahr, bmonat, btag) lack 1 char to store the \0

btag for instance should be btag[3], particularly since you are doing `btag[2] = 0` later in the source

Can you try adding 1 more char to all your strings and check if it corrects everything?

---

It should look like this:

`char name[21], bday[11], bjahr[5], bmonat[3], btag[3];`

if you want 20 chars max for the name, 10 for the bday, ...

then, when extracting the date:

```
strncpy(btag, &bday[0], 2);
    btag[2] = '\0';
```

This way, you copy 2 chars from bday in btag (starting at offset 0) and then you set the 3rd char to '\0' to end the string

Comment: really? my book, where i'm learning, always says that the 0 is also used, so if i say btag[2] i have the [0], the [1] an for the binary 0 the [2] so i can save 2 characters,

Comment: if you declare char btag[2], then you have btag[0] and btag[1] only (2 chars)

Comment: i've fixed it but i have still the same problem, no strings or numbers, just `\n`

Comment: you need to increase it for bday and bjahr too (not done in the issue description)

Comment: Also, if you are doing <code>strncpy(bmonat, &bday[3], 2);</code>, you need to follow it with <code>btag[2] = '\0';</code> and not btag[3]...

Comment: well bjahr and bmonat works fine now, just btag makes some trouble.

Comment: Can you update the main post to show the source code you're using right now? bday and bjahr still aren't declared with enough characters

Comment: actually it was the latest, but i posted it again, everything works now like i wanted it. except the part where i made a comment.

Comment: bday and bjahr still aren't declared with enough characters.

Comment: i don't understand, it do exactly what  i want. bday is big enough to take a date with the format 00.00.0000 and bjahr takes the last 4 characters from bday it works man, i compiled and tryed it. the only things that's breaks my head is btag

Comment: if you have wrongly declared / wrongly allocated variables, you can have issues later in the code: correct them first, this might solve everything

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with this.  For starters,
    bjahr[4] =  0;
    bmonat[2]=  0;
    btag[2]  =  0;

These are all trying to access things outside your size limitations on your buffer.

Another thing is that you are probably want

```
bjahr[4] =  '\0';
bmonat[2]=  '\0';
btag[2]  =  '\0';
```

Instead, as this gives you null characters instead of 0's.